# Is it possible to use "%of total" instead of "%of parent" in Wiztree?

Tags: disk-space, administration

Rather than knowing a file is 32% of 75% of 80% it would be more useful to plainly see what percent of the overall disk space it takes up. Is there a way to achieve this and see these percentages listed in the table?